# Обработать клавиши стрелок в input/sys.stdin python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, консоль

В функции `input` или при чтении из `stdin` в Python при попытке ввести стрелки (вправо и влево к примеру) выводится нечто типа `^[[A`, мне нужно как-то их (клавиши стрелок) обработать без нажатия клавиши `Return`.

Answer (score 2):

Основано на примере отсюда: [HOW TO IMPLEMENT KBHIT() ON LINUX (PYTHON RECIPE)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/572182-how-to-implement-kbhit-on-linux/)

Вкратце: нужно перевести терминал в небуферизированный режим (чтобы `read` возвращал считанные символы сразу, не дожидаясь Enter), перед чтением проверять, есть ли что читать.

```
import sys, termios, atexit
from select import select

# save the terminal settings
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
new_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
old_term = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

# new terminal setting unbuffered
new_term[3] = (new_term[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO)

# switch to normal terminal
def set_normal_term():
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, old_term)

# switch to unbuffered terminal
def set_curses_term():
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, new_term)

def kbhit():
    dr,dw,de = select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)
    return dr != []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    atexit.register(set_normal_term)
    set_curses_term()

    while True:
        if kbhit():
            key = sys.stdin.read(1)
            if key == '\x1b':
                # Если escape последовательность, то считать еще 2 символа 
                # Но будет некорректно работать, если был нажата клавиша Escape (будет ждать нажатия еще 2 кнопок)
                key += sys.stdin.read(2)

            print(repr(key))

            if key == '\x1b[A':
                print('Up')
            elif key == '\x1b[B':
                print('Down')
            elif key == '\x1b[C':
                print('Right')
            elif key == '\x1b[D':
                print('Left')
```

Очевидно, вариант с использованием библиотеки `curses` намного удобнее

Answer (score 1):

Для линукс есть стандартный модуль [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html) (текстовые окна)

```
import curses
import os

def main(win):
    win.nodelay(True)
    key=""
    win.clear()                
    win.addstr("Detected key:")
    while 1:          
        try:                 
           key = win.getkey()         
           win.clear()                
           win.addstr("Detected key:")
           win.addstr(str(key)) 
           if key == os.linesep:
              break           
        except Exception as e:
           # No input   
           pass         

curses.wrapper(main)
```

`^[[A` это эскейп последовательность. Они не попадают на текстовый stdin. Их можно прочесть с tty, но это слишком много кода для такой операции.

Если интересует физическая клавиатура, то можно пофильтровать evdev через [python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Escape последовательности попадают в stdin, но чтобы `sys.stdin.read()` их считал нужно нажать Enter, и для реализации простого текстового редактора, например, это не применимо. Можно конечно перевести терминал в небуферезированный режим, и проверять перед чтением, есть ли что-то в буфере, например как здесь: [HOW TO IMPLEMENT KBHIT() ON LINUX (PYTHON RECIPE)](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/572182-how-to-implement-kbhit-on-linux/) - но через cureses намного проще будет.

Comment: если  `.read(1)`?

Comment: Пробовал, все равно пока не нажмешь Enter, не выходит из read

Comment: Если бы мне нужно было решение на ncurses-like библиотеке - вопроса бы не было, но спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: Физическая клавиатура нужна или стандартный ввод?